# Phonegap cordova in xcode 4

Tags: html, xcode, cordova

I have installed phonegap onto my mac however when i click to create a new project there is no option for me to select a phonegap application in xcode.

Why is phonegap not displaying in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a "PhoneGap Application" in XCode by loading in the template that comes with the PhoneGap download. See the PhoneGap Getting Started Guide for iOS ([Link Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)). You basically need to run a terminal command to create a default XCode project, and then open it up in XCode.